# How to build a mobile app for employer with zero experience

Tags: android, mobile

I am doing some research for my employer. They would like to create a mobile app for their business.
My background is NOT in web/app development; however, I have been tasked to research the possibility of building it in-house. 
Therefore, I thought I would start at this forum, my questions are:
1.  Do you think this is possible? (I know some html, but not a lot)
2.  Could you recommend some tutorials for beginners?
3.  I have found some GoDaddy type websites for mobile apps, would this be a good option and any recommendations?
4.  If NO to all of the above, could a single contracted developer build? (nothing too complicated, imo)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This is not a forum site, but for specific programming Q&A. Please review: [On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [Don't Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO. 
Afraid this isn't really the place for this sort of question. But...

It entirely depends on what it is you want to do and how much time you've been given to do it. I built a fairly complex app with almost 0 experience when I first started. It's was terribly written but worked fine. There are loads of online resources to help but it isn't a small undertaking :)